# Interval of probabilities which satisfy a Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Given the following markov chain, where T1 is the start state, the labels are shown on the state( 'a' in this case) and p and 1-p are probabilities for that transition happening:

[image]

Now, for what values of p is it the case that there is greater than or equal to 0.5 chance of reaching state the labelled a, within a maximum of two steps, from the initial state T1?

So, say p=0.5 then, the transition $(T1 \rightarrow T2)$ will happen with a probability of $1-0.5=0.5$. But with the transitions $(T1 \rightarrow T1 \rightarrow T2)$ will happen with a probability of $p \times (1-p)$ i.e. $=0.5 \times (1-0.5) = 0.25$. So if p=0.5 this will be less than 0.5.

I can't get my head around finding the values for p where the overall probability of reaching label 'a' within a maximum of 2 steps is greater than 0.5. In PCTL this would be written as: $T1 \models P_{\geq 0.5} (F^{\leq 2} a)$

(Sorry for the poor drawing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have said, you need to solve $$(1-p)+p(1-p) \ge \frac12$$ subject to the usual condition for any probability that $0 \le p \le 1$.

This is at worst a quadratic which I will leave for you to solve.

Your example of $p=0.5$ has an error: the probability of reaching state $T_2$ in one step would indeed be $0.5$ and of reaching state $T_2$ exactly on the second step would be $0.25$.  So the probability of reaching state $T_2$ in a maximum of two steps would be $0.75 \gt 0.5$.

Comment: oh so I multiplied where I should've added the probabilities together?

Comment: Yes: the probability of *either* of two *mutually exclusive* events happening is the sum of their individual probabilities.  Contrast this with the probability of *both* of two *independent* events happening, which is the product of their individual probabilities.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. I see how I made a mistake there. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok at my first attempt, I get $0 \leq p \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$ but that doesn't look right?

Comment: Why not? $\sqrt{\frac12} \approx 0.7071$ and you would prefer $p$ to be small, to increase the chance of leaving $T_1$

Comment: Just looked at it again, seems right anyway! Thanks again.